# How to write subqueries?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to turn this SQL expression into a subquery using SQL Alchemy

I'm trying to read the documentation for subqueries but I'm lost. Can anyone write this in SqlAlchemy so I can understand how to do it?

```
SELECT from_ 
FROM uploaded_emails1
WHERE from_ != 'test@email.com'
AND from_ NOT IN (SELECT email FROM candidate_emails2)
```

Comment: I bet a join could be used here to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a left join instead of subquery :

```
SELECT from_ 
FROM uploaded_emails1 ue 
LEFT JOIN candidate_emails2 ce ON ue.from_ = ce.email 
WHERE ce.email IS NULL AND from_! = "test@email.com"
```

This could be expressed in SQLAlchemy as:

```
emails = dbsession.query(
    UploadedEmail.from_
).outerjoin(
    CandidateEmail, CandidateEmail.email == UploadedEmail.from_
).filter(
    CandidateEmail.email == None,
    UploadedEmail.from_ != 'test@email.com',
)
```

Comment: I am trying to write it in SQLAlchemy, not SQL

Comment: Once you get SQL it's pretty obvious how to write SQLAlchemy... Check my edit to see how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you might be trying to dive in a little bit at the deep end here (that SQL query is probably not really the right way to achieve what you want) so you might want to think about getting some SQL concepts a bit clearer in your head before diving into subqueries in sqlalchemy. Related to that, having tables named `uploaded_emails1` and `candidate_emails2` suggests that your underlying DB schema design might need a bit of tweaking.

That being said, here's a minimal example that should do what you want (get all email addresses that are in the uploaded emails that aren't also in the candidate emails table)

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import sqlalchemy as sq
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)

Base = declarative_base()


class UploadedUser(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'uploaded_user'
    uploaded_user_id = sq.Column(sq.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email_address = sq.Column(sq.Text(100))


class CandidateUser(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'candidate_user'

    candidate_user_id = sq.Column(sq.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email_address = sq.Column(sq.Text(100))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Candidate User with email: {}>'.format(self.email_address)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

uploaded_user = UploadedUser(email_address='email1@foo.com')
session.add(uploaded_user)

for idx in range(1, 3):
    candidate_user = CandidateUser(email_address='email{}@foo.com'.format(idx))
    session.add(candidate_user)

session.commit()

query_result = session.query(CandidateUser.email_address,
                             UploadedUser.email_address).outerjoin(UploadedUser,
                                                                   CandidateUser.email_address == UploadedUser.email_address).filter(
    UploadedUser.email_address.isnot(None)).with_entities(UploadedUser.email_address).all()

print(query_result)
```

The `echo=True` tells sqlalchemy to print the actual queries it's executing so the query you're talking about as executed is:

```
SELECT uploaded_user.email_address AS uploaded_user_email_address 
FROM candidate_user LEFT OUTER JOIN uploaded_user ON
candidate_user.email_address = uploaded_user.email_address 
WHERE uploaded_user.email_address IS NOT NULL
```

which is quite close to the query you'd want to write if you were writing raw SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
for email, in db_session.query(Uploaded_Emails1.from_).filter(
        Uploaded_Emails1.from_ != 'test@email.com').filter(
        ~Uploaded_Emails1.from_.in_(db_session.query(Candidate_Emails2.email))):
    print(email)
```

this worked